# Get text between two closed tags XML - Python

Tags: python, xml

I downloaded my Foursquare data and it comes in KML format.  I'm parsing through it as an XML file with Python and cannot figure out how to get the text between the closed a tag and closed description tag.  (It's the text that I typed when I checked in, in the example below it's "FINALLY HERE!! With Sonya and co" but there's also a hyphen).

This is an example of what the data looks like.

```
<Placemark>
  <name>hummus grill</name>
  <description>@<a href="https://foursquare.com/v/hummus-grill/4aab4f71f964a520625920e3">hummus grill</a>- FINALLY HERE!! With Sonya and co</description>
  <updated>Tue, 24 Jan 12 17:14:00 +0000</updated>
  <published>Tue, 24 Jan 12 17:14:00 +0000</published>
  <visibility>1</visibility>
  <Point>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>-75.20104383595685,39.9528387056977</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

So far I've been able to get the lat/longs, published dates, name, and link with code something like this for all:

```
latitudes = []
longitudes = []

for d in dom.getElementsByTagName('coordinates'):
    #Break them up into latitude and longitude
    coords = d.firstChild.data.split(',')
    longitudes.append(float(coords[0]))
    latitudes.append(float(coords[1]))
```

I tried this (below is the beginning of the data has this header thing, haven't figured out how to handle it yet)

```
for d in dom.getElementsByTagName('description'):
    description.append(d.firstChild.data.encode('utf-8'))

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml><Folder><name>foursquare checkin history </name><description>foursquare checkin history </description>:
```

and then accessing it by this     d.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data.encode('utf-8'), but it just gives me "hummus grill", what I'm assuming to be the text between the a tags (instead of from the name tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
In [44]: description = []

In [45]: for d in dom.getElementsByTagName('description'):
   ....:     description.append(d.firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.data.encode('utf-8'))
   ....:     

In [46]: description
Out[46]: ['- FINALLY HERE!! With Sonya and co']
```

Or, if you want the entire text in the description tag:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

def getText(node, recursive = False):
    """ 
    Get all the text associated with this node.
    With recursive == True, all text from child nodes is retrieved
    """
    L = ['']
    for n in node.childNodes:
        if n.nodeType in (dom.TEXT_NODE, dom.CDATA_SECTION_NODE):
            L.append(n.data)
        else:
            if not recursive:
                return None
        L.append(getText(n))
    return ''.join(L)

dom = parseString("""<Placemark>
  <name>hummus grill</name>
  <description>@<a href="https://foursquare.com/v/hummus-grill/4aab4f71f964a520625920e3">hummus grill</a>- FINALLY HERE!! With Sonya and co</description>
  <updated>Tue, 24 Jan 12 17:14:00 +0000</updated>
  <published>Tue, 24 Jan 12 17:14:00 +0000</published>
  <visibility>1</visibility>
  <Point>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>-75.20104383595685,39.9528387056977</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>""")

description = []

for d in dom.getElementsByTagName('description'):
    description.append(getText(d, recursive = True))

print description
```

This will print: `[u'@hummus grill- FINALLY HERE!! With Sonya and co']`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sub-strings?

Lets say that all of your xml is in the variable "foo" for example.

```
foo = '<description>@<a href="https://foursquare.com/v/hummus-grill/4aab4f71f964a520625920e3">hummus grill</a>- FINALLY HERE!! With Sonya and co</description>'
```

You could extract this data by printing the following.

```
foo[foo.index('</a>')+4:foo.index('</description>')]
```

This should give you what you want.

```
- FINALLY HERE!! With Sonya and co
```

Just read up on substrings and you'll be able to manipulate the text easier.

Comment: so would i need to convert the DOM element to a substring? or are you suggesting a different route altogether?

Comment: Yup. Making the entire DOM element one variable would make it easy for you to go back and pick apart certain pieces. Substrings just tend to be an easy way to parse text.